# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str' con cálculo matemático de porcentaje en bot de telegram

Tags: python

Estoy creando un bot para telegram con referencia en market data... El problema es al sacar el cálculo del porcentaje, me da el siguente error:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'

Aparentemente el error viene de los calls anteriores. ¿Hay alguna forma de mejorar esto sin intervenir en la modificación total?

```
def ticker_command():
Close = pdr.get_data_yahoo(empresas,    start=inicio,   end=fin)
CloseTodayfin = str(Close["Close"][0]. round(2))
CloseYesterday = pdr.get_data_yahoo(empresas,    start=ayer, end= ayer)
CloseYesterday = str(CloseYesterday["Close"][0]. round(2))
PercentChange = '{:.2%}' .format((CloseTodayfin*100)/CloseYesterday)
```

Answer (score 2):

Obviamente, creaste ambas variables como `str`:

```
CloseTodayfin = str(Close["Close"][0]. round(2))
CloseYesterday = str(CloseYesterday["Close"][0]. round(2))
```

por tanto, la división no va a resultar.

**Solución**

Deja las variables en su forma numérica original (sin usar `str`):

```
def ticker_command():
    Close = pdr.get_data_yahoo(empresas,    start=inicio,   end=fin)
    CloseTodayfin = Close["Close"][0]
    CloseYesterday = pdr.get_data_yahoo(empresas,    start=ayer, end= ayer)
    CloseYesterday = CloseYesterday["Close"][0]
    PercentChange = '{:.2%}' .format((CloseTodayfin*100)/CloseYesterday)
```

Comment: Gracias, entonces tendré que modificar el código... sin las variables str no puedo obtener los precios de cierre de las empresas.
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "numpy.float64") to str

Comment: OK. Es el típico problema donde necesitas `str` en una parte e `int` en otra. Si tienes que manejar ambas, tendrás que hacer conversiones explicitas donde se necesite. Sorry.